# Android, Espresso, WireMock: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder;

Tags: android, wiremock

Android Studio 2.3.1:

My build.gradle

```
    defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 44
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled = true
}
```

dependencies {
    // for folder "test"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.6'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.6'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:+"

```
//------ Compile Dependencies ------
compile('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
}
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'
compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.5.0"
compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12"

//------ Android Test Dependencies ------
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
    exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
}
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'

androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

//MockWebServer - Version 2.2 of mockwebserver doesn't work because of an issue, so forcing v2.1 - https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1069
androidTestCompile('com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.5.0') {
    exclude module: 'okhttp'
}

//WireMock
androidTestCompile("com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:2.5.0") {
     exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-api'
    exclude group: 'org.ow2.asm', module: 'asm'
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}
androidTestCompile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
androidTestCompile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'

androidTestCompile "com.squareup.spoon:spoon-client:1.5.6"
```

}

My wiremock and espresso test:

```
public class WireMockApplicationTestCase2 {

Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WireMockApplicationTestCase2.class);
WireMockServer wireMockServer;


@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

private Context androidTestContext;
private Context applicationContext;


@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    this.androidTestContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();
    this.applicationContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();
    wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(8089);
    wireMockServer.start();
}

/**
 * Test WireMock, but just the Http Call.  Make sure the response matches the mock we want.
 */
@Test
public void testWiremockPlusOkHttp() throws IOException {
    logger.debug("testWiremockPlusOkHttp>>>>>>>>>>>>>");

    String serviceEndpoint = "http://127.0.0.1:" + 8089;
    logger.debug("WireMock Endpoint: " + serviceEndpoint);

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = null;

    String uri = "/hello-world";
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(serviceEndpoint + uri)
            .build();

    Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();

    String responseBodyStr = response.body().string();

    logger.debug("Response Body>>>>>>>: " + responseBodyStr);
    assertEquals("hello world", responseBodyStr);
}
```

}

But when I start test on Android 7.0  get error:

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder;
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.HttpClientFactory.createClient(HttpClientFactory.java:48)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.ProxyResponseRenderer.<init>(ProxyResponseRenderer.java:53)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockApp.buildStubRequestHandler(WireMockApp.java:124)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer.<init>(WireMockServer.java:71)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer.<init>(WireMockServer.java:108)
at com.myproject.android.transport.WireMockApplicationTestCase2.setUp(WireMockApplicationTestCase2.java:46)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```